# Is the newborn naturally unclean with the mother, or contingently if it comes in contact?

Tags: halacha

Does the newborn also share the uncleanness with the mother due to birth, Lev. 12, is the child source of the impurity?

What is the Halakah ruling for purification of the husband or child who comes in contact with her or if it is naturally unclean as the source of her impurity? However, the main question is this: when the mother goes for purification rites to the temple after the whole purification period, does she takes along the child as well since this period pertains to the child as well. If the child is the source of impurity then the rites particularly is meant for the child, then its mother.

Also, have commentators used such verses to support this:

> (ESV) Psalm 51:5: “Behold, I was brought forth in iniquity, and in sin did my mother conceive me.”
> Job 15:14: “What is man, that he can be pure? Or he who is born of a woman, that he can be righteous?”
> Job 25:4: “How then can man be in the right before God? How can he who is born of woman be pure?”

[image]
Need full text of this  Sifra Tazria Parashat Yoledet
(the earliest known Rabbinic commentary on Lev. 12), The actual argument is complicated. That children are a source of uncleanness is denied in Section 8, but re-affirmed in Section 11.

I need as ancient sources as possible from commentaries or any Jewish literature. Quote English translation for every text.

Comment: Not sure your question is so clear. Leviticus 12 speaks of circumcision and the animal sacrifices a woman would bring post-birth. Exodus 13:2 speaks of redeeming the firstborn by which one "buys back" symbolically a male firstborn from a Kohen (priest tribe). Does this help refine your question?

Comment: Tags will need to be edited once we know what you are asking about

Comment: Exodus offering is described with "Consecrate to me the firstborn", thus I used consecration. The question is a) is the child also requires purification from the Lev 12 purification of the mother; and if this same purification offering can also be lumped with the consecration/redemption offering, acc to historical sources of the law. I have seen reference that sources: Jubilees, 4Q265,&66 assume the purification of infants along with the mothers. I suppose we can find rabbinic or Mishna sources for the same.

Comment: You must be learning from a translation which is confusing you. Lev 12 speaks of a new mother going to a ritual bath after a defined period (depending on the child being a boy or girl), the sacrifices she should bring and a boy's circumcision. There is no child purification concept here.

Comment: If you want to ask about specific verses, please give verse numbers as well as a link to the translation you are using so we can check if it matches the original Hebrew

Comment: There is no reference of the ablution in Lev 12, but implied, the same way, it maybe for the purification offering of the newborn. Can you access this article, p 15. PURIFICATION AFTER CHILDBIRTH AND THE SACRED GARDEN IN 4Q265 AND JUBILEES by Joseph Baumgarten?

Comment: If you want to discuss a specific paper, please provide a link to it. In any case, it seems the purification you speak about are sacrifices the mother offered in the Temple. The child was not involved. Ex 13:2 speaks of the firstborn being God's so to speak which leads to the symbolic redeeming of that firstborn baby. No sacrifice here.

Comment: all animal killings in such context are sacrifices. The text does not speak of woman's ablution either. You seem to be naive beginner in theological studies. I suggest you relax and wait for some answers.

Comment: I was trying to help you clarify your question and comments. You speak of purification of the child (which doesn't exist in Torah), tag your question as halacha. None of this makes much sense. Also Lev 12:2 makes reference to a woman's immersion in a mikve (and indeed 13 references are made to that verse in tractate Nidda). But fine, we can also wait to see what happens to this question as is.

Comment: Bec i didnt find purification tag, I used halakah, coz it's a legal question. Where is the ref for immersion here? (12:2) “Speak to the people of Israel, saying, If a woman conceives and bears a male child, then she shall be unclean seven days. As at the time of her menstruation, she shall be unclean.

Comment: The verse speaks of "yemei nidat", the days of her impurity. The remedy for nida is immersion, thus the 13 references to this verse in tractate Nida which deals with the immersion of a nida woman

Comment: Good. The same way I am asking others to find ref about the child's purification or uncleanness along with the mother.

Comment: @User123 you should post an answer with all details with translation; what's the time of this Raavad and if he mentions the purification rites for the child? I also wanna know if someone has argued that it is the child which makes the mother unclean, rather than mother making the child unclean; as the Jubilees 3:8–13 story of Adam Eve having to wait for their corresponding period before entering the Garden; and the (Dosithean) Samaritan also somewhat includes the child in Lev 12; along with all ancient civilizations.

Comment: What does weening have to do with anything?

Comment: because if the child is not naturally born unclean and later becomes unclean due to contact then it cannot touch the unclean mother, hence some sources forbid the weaning and force a wet nurse until the mothers purification periods fulfills.

Comment: @user123  what is the period of man becoming unclean from touching the unclean new mother? And is it normal and usual that a man touches her and becomes unclean, or it is very unusual and abhorrent for the man?

Comment: I am not asking about modern times that you are saying there is no prohibition to come in contact. Within the realm of Biblical law and post-Biblical Jewish religious discourse surrounding tumah and taharah, the impurity is called in Hebrew tumat yoledet. Halakhah treats a yoledet (woman who gives birth) similarly to any woman with niddah status.

 For example, there was a Sana Yemenite custom of women visiting the mother during 4–6 weeks after childbirth. The mother would be visited in a special room in her home and she would sit in a decorated triangle box

Comment: I think weaning means the opposite of the way you're using it

Answer (score 1):

The child would indeed be ritually impure as he has touched the mother throughout childbirth (although it might only be contracted once he's born and touches her then). This is because a woman who has given birth (a yoledes) transmits impurity via touch. See eg [Maimonides](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Those_Who_Defile_Bed_or_Seat.1.1?lang=en#:)

However this impurity would be a lower level than the mother, as is explicit in [Sifra Tazria #8](https://www.sefaria.org/Sifra%2C_Tazria_Parashat_Yoledet%2C_Section_1.8?lang=bi) (second part of the section) which states that despite causing tumah, and being able to become tameh, the child is not impure itself.

> תאמר בולד שיש לו טומאה! הואיל ויש לו טומאה יהא טמא! תלמוד לומר "וטמאה" – **היא טמאה ואין הולד טמא**.

> Would you say the same of the child, which is subject to tumah in and of itself? Since it is subject to tumah, it should be tamei (in birth)! It must, therefore, be written "she shall be unclean," **and not the child.**

It would thus be considered no different to any other person who touched her. Like all these people, no sacrifices would be required for the child (unlike the mother)

Either way, there is no prohibition in becoming impure, and certainly not for a baby. It would confer certain restrictions (eg not eating sacrificial meat or visiting the Temple in Jerusalem) and at some point to remove the restrictions he would need to be immersed.

I have never heard of any custom, modern or ancient, that would restrict a mother from feeding her child - as above, there is no prohibition in becoming impure.

Comment: I found ancient ref of Qumran text that forbids the child and forces a wet nurse for breastfeeding. Thanks. Can u focus on aifra tazria text to quote it and argue on whether child makes her unclean or she makes him unclean. The main question I wanna ask is when the mother goes for purification rites at the temple Lev 12, is it natural that she goes along with the child, as the period of purification pertains to both of them (and not to mother and the father).

Comment: I can't comment for the Essenes (who had any number of divergent practices) but within Rabbinic Judaism there has never been an issue. I've edited my answer to note that only the mother needs the sacrifice, not the child (who is like anyone else). I can't find any reference in Sifra to the child being impure, and there is no reason to assume he is intrinsically so.

Comment: The screenshot shows the section 5 stating the child is the source. Can't u find and quote it? If yes then the child must go with her for purification rites and the child and mother both inherently shares the impurity for the whole period. The other family members can avoid the small one day impurity which requires no special rites.

Comment: That isn't what it means. It just means that she becomes impure because she gave birth to him.

Comment: It can be interpreted that way. He makes her impure, not she made him. And the purification rites in Lev 12, thus pertains mainly to the child, but the mother shares it. I have references like some Samaritan source on Lev 12 which includes the child in the impurity.

Comment: There is no implication in the verse that he is tameh. If Sifra meant that it would have had to derive it from somewhere, which it doesn't. This is then borne out from the silence of Maimonides (linked above). As with the Essenes, Samaritan practice is of no relevance

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150281/discussion-between-aka-and-michael16).

Comment: Thank you for taking this one on!