# Is it normal for the husband to become unclean by touching the unclean wife from new birth or niddah?

Tags: halacha

Is it normal and acceptable according to halacha that the husband inevitably becomes unclean by coming in contact with his wife during niddah period? Or it is very shameful and considered abhorrent, sinful to do so?

Is it shameful, disgraceful, sinful for the husband if he comes in contact with the niddah wife/ new-mother. In other words, during childbirth, is it natural and acceptable that he touches her for any assistance and becomes unclean for a day, or it would be very rare and only accidentally or unlikely that one may frown upon being unclean. Lev 15.19 *whoever touches her shall be unclean until the evening*; and for the new-mother, the man would most likely not touch her until her full purification period of 33 or 66 days completes.

wiki: [Impurity after child birth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impurity_after_childbirth)

> Within the realm of Biblical law and post-Biblical Jewish religious
> discourse surrounding tumah and taharah, the impurity is called in
> Hebrew tumat yoledet. Halakhah treats a yoledet (woman who gives
> birth) similarly to any woman with niddah status.
>
> In some Jewish communities, ceremonies and a degree of seclusion were
> applied to postparturient women. For example, there was a Sana
> Yemenite custom of women visiting the mother during 4–6 weeks after
> childbirth. The mother would be visited in a special room in her home
> and she would sit in a decorated triangle box

Post English translations of all your quotes and try to cite old sources. I am asking for historical Jewish practice, not the modern culture which wouldn't observe such rituals.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "normal". In general, the Torah describes how things can become ritually unfit and the various methods to return to a state of ritual fitness when it occurs. For most people, it is simply part of the process of life. In general, it is preferable, when possible, to remain in a state of being ritually fit for a variety of reasons. But to emphasize, engaging in reproduction, which is the first commandment of the Torah, by necessity involves one in that cycle.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niddah go read that.

Comment: I mean is it shameful, disgraceful, sinful for the husband if he comes in contact with the niddah wife/ newmother. In other words, during child birth, is it natural and acceptable that he touches her for any assistance and becomes unclean for a day, or it would be very rare and only accidentally or unlikely that one may frown upon being unclean. Lev 15.20  whoever touches her shall be unclean until the evening.; and for new-mother, the man would most likely not touch her until her full purification period of 33 or 66 days completes.

Comment: I mean if the husband becomes unclean, or the other women who comes in contact with niddah due to child birth assistance, they only becomes defiled for one day, so that's not a big deal, right? However, an ideal person would not come in contact and this one day transmission of niddah would still be frowned upon and avoided by most people, right?

Comment: The husband wouldn't touch her because of the prohibited relations. For anybody else -- precisely as you stated. Everybody was going to be "ritually impure" sooner or later; in Temple times it was a routine part of their life, and you just knew that occasionally you couldn't go to the Temple or eat a sacrifice. But you're correct: the midwife, sister, or anybody else helping out -- they'd all be "ritually impure" the day they rendered assistance, then would immerse later that day and be all done at nightfall. It wasn't shameful, it was a fact of life.

Comment: Dad comes home -- *Hey kids! I just came home from the Temple with some sacrificial meat, who wants some?* Johnny: "Sorry dad; they was some pauper whose family needed help with the burial today." Dad: *You absolutely did the right thing; we'll get you some sacrificial meat next week.* Susie: "Sorry dad, I was helping Mrs. Smith next door who just had a baby." Dad: *You also did the right thing; we'll get you some sacrificial meat tomorrow.*

Comment: thanks, now more specifically, is Lev 15.19 the normal niddah period of 7 days, and if it becomes serious and exceeds then it becomes zivah? verse 25? in this case does the one who touches her still just waits for one day or his requirement is increased, by "washing" v27, and in any case, if the one who touches her like family, during childbirth, and their time remains just one day then it's not a big deal, and the family definitely doesn't need to offer any sacrifice. Only the woman needs the sacrifice, right? Lev 12? also plz answer on my other question with full text of one source image

Comment: Please break this into individual questions. This has gone rather freewheeling.

Comment: No, I get it, it remedy may just increase for zavah contraction with washing, whereas normal niddah contraction requires just one day period to be clean again. Plz see the other topic and find the full quote of sifra and related texts https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/138797/is-the-newborn-naturally-unclean-with-the-mother-or-contingently-if-it-comes-in

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most of the laws of ritual impurity don't make a difference today. People have gone to graveyards, but there's not Red Cow ash to purify them from that. Then again, there's no Temple nor sacrifices right now, so if someone's ritually impure, that doesn't really restrict much.

The critical exception is that marital relations are prohibited during the *Nidah* period. That applies even if everyone is "ritually impure" anyhow because, for instance, they both touched dead lizards today. Or he's an undertaker. There are various verses about this in a few different places in the Bible, and a lot of detail is left to the tradition recorded in the Talmud. Thus, I'll refer you to Maimonides' code, [Chapter 4 of Prohibited Relations](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Forbidden_Intercourse.4.1?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en). (He consolidated the relevant laws in a very clear fashion.) The stuff about ritual impurity vis-a-vis the Temple appears in a different book of his.

Let's grossly oversimplify and say that Nidah begins with the onset of menstrual bleeding. It then continues for five days or the cessation of bleeding, whichever is more; then requires seven clean days; then requires immersion in a Mikvah.

Childbirth basically is treated the same as Nidah today; as bleeding usually can continue for several weeks, it means waiting several weeks for the cessation of bleeding, then seven clean days, then Mikvah.

While a woman is in the state of Nidah, the issue with her husband touching her today has nothing to do with everything you're seeing in Leviticus. It's that once relations are prohibited, [they should avoid touching](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/52940/what-is-the-source-of-shomer-negiah) as a way of staying far away from prohibited behavior.

Most Orthodox rabbis today therefore apply those laws directly, and would apply a blanket rule -- once labor starts, the woman is a *Nidah*, ergo her husband should not touch her until several weeks have passed, plus Mikvah. (And if he does, well ... just don't do it again!)

(If we worried about the technical ritual impurity as you're seeing in Leviticus, then if she sat on a couch at 8am, then went to work, and he sat on the couch at 9am, he'd be "impure" ... again, today, not a problem.)

One could attempt to argue that touch that's purely for emotional support, in a context where it won't lead to anything else, might be different ... but generally the Orthodox position is that a blanket rule was stated, as otherwise everyone would make their own exceptions, and slippery-slope their way from there.

Comment: Good answer. But I wanted to add that if I wasn't willing to touch my wife, hug her, or hold her hand through her birthing process I'm not sure I'd be married anymore. Or at the very least, my wife wouldn't have wanted more than 1 kid with me considering how absent I would have been for the most painful process of her life. So it's always worth checking in with your wife to get her expectations during childbirth.

Comment: Plz confirm this. Can we translate Lev 12 like this if without vowel marks? Without the vocalization, the Masoretic Text of Lev 12:4 proves more ambiguous: bothדמי טהרה andימי טהרה could be read without the mappiq on the final he to mean “blood of purification” and “days of purification,” respectively, rather than the blood and days of her purification. The Masoretes add a mappiq to the second nominal construction to clarify that the text is speaking of “days of her purification.”